# Convert a Column of a Dataframe using Shapely

Tags: python, pandas, shapely

I'm trying to convert a whole column of a DataFrame to a geometry column using shapely.

After reading the file into pandas, I convert one value of the column using the next code:

```
from shapely.wkb import loads
geometry=loads('0101000020E61000006A6AD95A5FCC58C0A6272CF1807A3340', hex=True)
geometry.wkt
```

and the output is `'POINT (-99.19332 19.47853)'`

but i need to convert all the column and idk how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply` with right parameter:

Input data:

```
>>> df
                                         data
0  0101000000715AF0A2AF064140D6E59480988F5DC0
1  0101000000B610E4A0845D44401FF64201DB7B52C0
2  0101000000BE67244223E04740FFE7305F5E2F5EC0
```

```
df['geometry'] = df['data'].apply(loads, hex=True)
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
                                         data                       geometry
0  0101000000715AF0A2AF064140D6E59480988F5DC0  POINT (34.052235 -118.243683)
1  0101000000B610E4A0845D44401FF64201DB7B52C0    POINT (40.73061 -73.935242)
2  0101000000BE67244223E04740FFE7305F5E2F5EC0  POINT (47.751076 -120.740135)
```